# JavaScript: Replacing characters on both sides of a string

Tags: javascript, regex

What I want to do is to match characters enclosed by `^^` and replace those `^^` while maintaining the string. In other words, turning this:

```
^^This is a test^^ this is ^^another test^^
```

into this:

```
<sc>This is a test</sc> this is <sc>another test</sc>
```

I got the regex to match them:

```
\^{2}[^^]+\^{2}
```

But I'm stuck there. I'm not sure what to do with the other `.replace` parameter:

```
.replace(/\^{2}[^^]+\^{2}/g, WHAT_TO_ADD_HERE?)
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use replace with regex and grouping like

```
var text = '^^This is a test^^ this is ^^another test^^'.replace(/\^\^(.*?)\^\^/g, '<sc>$1</sc>')
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a piece of code you can use:

```
var re = /(\^{2})([^^]+)(\^{2})/g; 
var str = '^^This is a test^^ this is ^^another test^^\n\n<sc>This is a test</sc> this is <sc>another test</sc>';
var subst = '<sc>$2</sc>'; 

var result = str.replace(re, subst);
```

This is just an enhancement of your regex pattern where I added capturing groups. To improve performance and ensure you will be capturing all symbols between the `^^`, you can use only one capturing group and `.` symbol with *non-greedy quantificator*:

```
var re = /\^{2}(.+?)\^{2}/g;
```

Have a look at [the example](https://regex101.com/r/oU7xY9/4).

Answer (score 1):

In this case you need to use the group index to wrap the content.

```
var content  = "^^This is a test^^ this is ^^another test^^";

content.replace(/\^{2}(.*?)\^{2}/g, '<sc>$1</sc>');
```

The `(.*?)` will help you to group the content and in your replace statement use $1 where 1 is the index of group.

Comment: +1 for the bit of explanation on what's going on (although basically its the same answer then the one of @Arun P Johny)